# Multiprocessing Pool() equivalent for non-picklable objects

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pickle, whoosh

**Short**

Is there an equivalent to the `multiprocessing.Pool()`'s `map` function for non-picklable objects in python 3? Or do I misunderstand this error? :

> TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects

---

**Long**

I have a large [`whoosh`](http://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) index (text indexing and searching library) which sometimes takes time to query.

So in order to speed up computations I split it into 5 different indexes so that I can query them with 5 different *processes*.

I do not want to re-open the `index` every time so I want to feed my search function with an opened `index` as argument. This object is not picklable so I can't use `multiprocessing.Pool()`'s `map` function to run 5 processes querying the 5 different (opened) indexes.

I therefore tried `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()` to do the job with *threads* but it does not seem to really speed up computations.

- Am I missing something here and there is an easier way to speed up such computations?
- In Python 3 is there a way to use multiple *processes* for such non-picklable objects?
- Maybe I misunderstand this error : `TypeError: can't pickle memoryview objects`

Comment: Relevant: [how-can-i-make-this-un-pickleable-object-pickleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699391/python-how-can-i-make-this-un-pickleable-object-pickleable)