# How do I store an object that is non-pickleable?

Tags: python, pickle

I am working on a discord bot with nextcord, and want to save a discord user object on command. I have this code:

```
@commands.command()
     async def record(self, item):
     pickle.dump(item, open("filepath.txt", "wb"))
```

In discord that would be run like this:

```
.record @Username#0000
```

It is supposed to pickle the user object (@Username#0000) to filepath.txt, but instead it throws this error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskStepMethWrapper' object
```

Is there any other way to store and load objects that would be able to store and load 'TaskStepMethWrapper' object?

Comment: One option is always to pickle the member variables of the object. That also makes the pickling resilient to changes to the source code of the class

Comment: I also need to reconstruct the object, so that would not work.

Comment: Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699391/python-how-can-i-make-this-un-pickleable-object-pickleable

Comment: What exactly are you passing to `record`? (What appears to be) a method wrapper doesn't seem like something you need to save and restulore.

Comment: I am passing a Nextcord User Object to record

Comment: I was assuming you had written the class yourself, and would be able to add the code to reconstruct objects in the constructor, or similar. Depending on how the objects are created, you still might be able to reconstruct objects by writing your own function.

Comment: I attempted using this post: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699391/python-how-can-i-make-this-un-pickleable-object-pickleable) And I couldn't get it to work for my purposes. Is there any other way?